# Unable to build Android+Scala project using sbt+sbt-android plugin

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I can't build Android + Scala (and IntelliJ Idea 12) project using sbt and [sbt-android plugin](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin). I installed everything needed and added ANDROID_SDK_HOME to both `.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` but:

```
me123@ubuntu:~/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project$ echo $ANDROID_SDK_HOME
/home/me123/android-sdk-linux/sdk

me123@ubuntu:~/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project$ sudo echo $ANDROID_SDK_HOME
/home/me123/android-sdk-linux/sdk

me123@ubuntu:~/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/me123/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/me123/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/project
[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to /home/me123/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
[error] /home/me123/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes/AndroidEclipse$Transformer.class (Permission denied)
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q


me123@ubuntu:~/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project$ sudo sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /home/me123/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/me123/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/project/}default-6ff5da...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_0;0.12.2 ...
[info] Done updating.
[error] Android SDK not found. You might need to set ANDROID_SDK_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT or ANDROID_HOME
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

**UPDATE**:

```
    > android:start-device
[info] Wrote /home/alex/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/scala/my/android/project/TR.scala
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/alex/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[warn] there were 4 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
ProGuard, version 4.6
ProGuard is released under the GNU General Public License. You therefore
must ensure that programs that link to it (scala, ...)
carry the GNU General Public License as well. Alternatively, you can
apply for an exception with the author of ProGuard.
Reading program directory [/home/alex/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/target/scala-2.10/classes]
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last main/android:proguard for the full output.
[error] (main/android:proguard) java.io.IOException: Can't read [/home/alex/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/target/scala-2.10/classes] (Can't process class [my/android/project/R$id.class] (Unsupported version number [51.0] for class format))
[error] Total time: 14 s, completed May 30, 2013 3:49:46 PM
```

Comment: @om-nom-nom don't you see what it shows?

Comment: Sorry, somehow, I missed the output :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, doing `sudo echo $ANDROID_HOME` will be exactly the same as `echo $ANDROID_HOME`, because the variable will be replaced by your shell *before* executing the command.

Then, you most likely have a permission problem. Try running this to make sure you have the right ones :

```
$ chmod -Rv 700 /home/me123/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/
```

Comment: it said `mode of /home/me123/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/...........' changed from 0775 (rwxrwxr-x) to 0700 (rwx------)` but the error(s) for sudo sbt and sbt remain.

Comment: note that android sdk home directory  are actually located at another logic drive but there is a simlink to it at /home/me123/android-linux-sdk (/home/me123/android-linux-sdk -> another logic drive).

Comment: Can you try reading (with Vim or Gedit or whatever) the class file directly?

Comment: yes, I can `gedit /home/me123/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes/AndroidEclipseDefaults$$anonfun$settings$1.class`, it happens to be empty, though.

Comment: Did you run anything as a different user, by any chance? Because `Permission denied` doesn't happen for a lot of other reasons... What are the permissions of `/home/me123/Documents/android_projects/my-android-project/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes/AndroidEclipse$Transformer.class`?

Comment: there is another issue, however.