# How can I use a combination of Scala, Groovy, and Java code with Gradle?

Tags: scala, groovy, gradle, android-studio

Recently I'm trying to make some Android apps with Android Studio.

Does the built-in Gradle plugin support using a combination of Java, Groovy, and Scala code for building an Android app?

Looking at the the `gradle-android` wiki, I've found that `sourceSet` does not work with Android Studio (get "R redefined" error).

I'm using the default Gradle Wrapper way in Android Studio.

How do I use a mix of Scala, Groovy, and Java code in my Android Studio project?

[image: My Project Screenshot here]

I've tried to add some directives to **build.gradle** (like using `apply plugin` and  `sourceSets`), but they don't seem to work.

I think changing some code like **homeactivity.java** into **homeactivity.groovy** might work, but I've not found the way to do this yet.

When I uncomment the `sourceSets` block, I get this error message:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':AgricolaScore'.
> Could not find method groovy() for arguments [build_3cmthdr3hv9648pq38oficf549$_run_closure3_closure6_closure8_closure10@15f565e7] on source set main.
```

Comment: @dmahapatro, what I can do to turn this question 'on hold' to normal??

Comment: You can edit the question to address the concern that it is primarily opinion based. For more help on what "on hold" means, you should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) relevant page from the help center (which can be accessed by clicking "help" in the top bar).

Comment: He already edited the question; now what?  Admittedly, the edits were rather minor.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this might not be the answer you're looking for, but AFAIK, the porting of Groovy to Android has been tried twice and never completed. There was a [GSoC proposition](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GSoC+2013) this summer, but I don't know if it has been picked up. Which means no groovy code can run on a Dalvik VM just yet, and of course gradle cannot do anything about that.

I don't know much about Scala, but it looks like Scala code can be compiled to run on Dalvik, so you should have more luck there. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750642/intellij-idea-12-android-scala-nowadays), for example, to use the Scala Build Tool to build for Android.

EDIT: This needs to be edited since things have changed just recently: the last gr8conf saw the introduction of [grooid](http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/06/grooid.html) by Cédric Champeau, which allows to run groovy code on android. Yay !

Comment: It appears that Mr. Champeau's work is best accessed with this recently updated android studio plugin https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Groovy, the answer from Sensei seems to me good.

Regarding Scala you really need to replace Gradle by SBT for the dependency management.

Then you need a plugin.

I have tried two of them:

- https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin
- http://fxthomas.github.io/android-plugin/ (this is the link to the tuto)

The second one has a nice tuto, but doesn't work so well with Intellij Idea.

So I am using the first one. It s pretty easy to setup (read the ... read me) and using Java + Scala in the same project doesn't imply any special configuration. The last commit is 6 days old (as of today, the 11/11/13), and the project is two years old so I believe it won't die soon.

I know there is a third plugin to support Android on SBT but as far as I know the dev is stopped.

Hope it will help you.

Regards