# Using a Scala library for an Android application

Tags: android, scala

I have a Scala module (library) which I want to use for my Android application. Is it possible? If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's certainly possible. You just need to include the Scala standard library as well and use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to remove its unused parts and decrease the size of your application. See e.g. http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/androiddevelopment/index.html (for Eclipse) and [IntelliJ Idea 12 + Android + Scala nowadays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750642/intellij-idea-12-android-scala-nowadays) (for IDEA).