# Scala library for Android

Tags: java, android, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I read a topic [IntelliJ Idea 12 + Android + Scala nowadays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750642/intellij-idea-12-android-scala-nowadays) which seemed to be pretty much what I need. However, I need something slightly different: I want just to create a library in Scala and use it in android project. That android project can use Java or Scala also, it doesn't matter. I don't want to create a whole android project in Scala.

So how do I create such a library?

Do I need to create **an android project** using the tutorials from here http://fxthomas.github.io/android-plugin/ ? Or **a normal scala library** which doesn't know about android at all (the fact that it will be used in an android project), and then when I add it to an android project I'll have to add scala support somehow?

P.S. I use IntelliJ Idea 12 and sbt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to tell if you need an Android (library-) project or a common Scala application you need to be clear about your use case. In fact you have to ask yourself the very same question when you are building an Android library the Java way.

When your library provides any kind of resources (graphics, xml-views, ...) then you'll need to create a library project because when you wrap the project into a `*.jar` file these resources will not be accessible any more. When you create a library project, then you're also providing the library's source code to your users.

If this is not the case and all you want to build ends up in `*.class` files you can go ahead with a common Scala project. The resulting `*.jar` file can then be used as library. And even in such a Scala project you may reference the Android API if you add the `android.jar` to your project dependencies.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.android" % "android" % "4.1.1.4" % "provided"
```

Comment: are you saying, I can create a scala library and just add it as a dependency to an Android application the same as it were a Java library?

Comment: If this Android application is written in Scala as well, then it'll work flawlessly. When the Android application interacts with your Scala library via Java code then you're stepping into the lion's den. Using Scala code from Java is (in general; not Android related) a hassle and requires you to take care of which features you're using on the Scala end. It's possible though..

Comment: and if it's written in Java?